# Why am I getting this unexpected token error?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

This is how my code goes. However I keep getting this error. I am not sure why. Could someone kindly help me?

syntax error near unexpected token `echo'

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add code in place of image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also consider running it through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) for automated troubleshooting

Comment: Since you tagged this `sh` instead of `bash`, the `function` keyword isn't valid at all. The only POSIX sh standard-compliant way to define a function is with `localiser() {` (and also, POSIX sh doesn't standardize `local` at all, though common implementations like dash do tend to support it anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is important here. `{` is only special if it is a word by itself. What you have here is an attempt to define a function named `localiser{`, but with the simple command `echo ...` as the body. Function bodies must be compound commands (usually `{ ... }`).

Defining a function with the `function` keyword isn't really recommended; it exists many for compatibility with `ksh`. Use the following form instead:

```
localiser () {
    ...
}
```